# EF6 Application Code

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I'm migrating to Entity Framework v6 and I'm struggling to build code that will let me define my SQL 2008R2 database connection in the code.  I cannot store the connection string information within the app.config file due to this library being a dll that multiple applications will be using.  The idea is to maintain all the Database connections within 1 dll without having to reference the entity-libraries in the front-ends nor specify a connection string.

With EF5 I was able to  use a partial class and define the connection string in the DBContext, that method does not seem to work with EF6.  I'd like an example of an EF6 SQL database connection entirely defined within code.  Most of the examples of EF6 out there are for code-first models, I already have the database tables, I just need to build the interface.

-Hiram

Comment: Why can't each application have its own app.config file?

Comment: Also, are you saying you want to maintain all Database connection strings or connection objects within the 1 DLL you mentioned? Please clarify.

Comment: The scenario is like this:

DLL Maintains all of the connections to the database.  All connection strings and so forth.  Child applications just call the DLL and treat the DLL as a black box.  

With current development, when I reference the DLL with another project in the same solution (or different solution) it complains that no connection string is found.  I thought that coding the connection string into the DLL itself would eliminate that confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(assuming that you are using the EF Designer)

You can't just pass a connection string to the DbContext when using the code generated from the EF6 Designer because the DbContext needs the information created from the EDMX.  But you can still create a partial class that has a constructor that accepts a connection string.  You will just have to create an ObjectContext and pass that to the DbContext constructor.

Here is an example:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Northwind.Model {
    public partial class NorthwindEntities {
        public NorthwindEntities(string connectionString)
            : base(GetObjectContext(connectionString), true) {
        }

        private static ObjectContext GetObjectContext(string connectionString) {
            // You can use the metadata portion of the connection string the the designer added to your config for the paths
            var paths = new[] { 
                "res://*/Northwind.csdl", 
                "res://*/Northwind.ssdl", 
                "res://*/Northwind.msl"
            };

            var workspace = new MetadataWorkspace(paths, new[] { typeof(NorthwindEntities).Assembly });
            var connection = new EntityConnection(workspace, new SqlConnection(connectionString));

            return new ObjectContext(connection);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still define the connection string in the DBContext in EF6.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base(@"Your connection string here") { }

 // Rest of your DbContext code

}
```

But hard coding a connection string in there isn't very versatile. Even though your `DbContext` will be in it's own dll, it can still read the `app.config` or `web.config` of your primary project if it is in the same solution (and I'm fairly sure it will work even if you add your `DbContext` dll as a reference).

Just add a reference to `System.Configuration` in your `DbContext` project, and then you can get at the connection string with either `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString` or `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyConnectionStringName"]`

And you would store the connection string in your primary applications `web.config` in the `<connectionStrings>` section OR in the 'app.config' in the `<appSettings>` section

Note that if you do it this way (by reading from `web.config` or `app.config`), you should change your `DbContext` code accordingly:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyConnectionStringName") { }

 // Rest of your DbContext code

}
```